# Which is the purpose of port 6443

Tags: https, port, admin, malware

there,

Which application uses port 6443 and for what? I want this information because when I use the command nmap with mi ip, there is a line that puts "6443 sun-sr-https". Is it something about oracle? sr means "server"?

And in other port, in 9090, I have "zeus-admin". I read about it in some places and in there they said that it is some kind of malware. Is it correct? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 27):

kube-apiserver which is one of Kubernetes components uses port 6443 too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the original question, the title of the post comes up in my search for port 6443, and this answer helped me determine my own issue. So I'm undoing the downvote =)

Answer (score 13):

The service name `sun-sr-https` is the name of the [Oracle Service Registry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/registry/overview/index.html) which (according to  [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-4640/gakvo/index.html)) uses the 6443 port for HTTPS over SSL connections as an alternative to the default well-known port 443 so *as not to cause conflicts with the default Application Server domain*.

Many applications use the 6443 port as an alternative to the default one, for example, the Kubernetes API. Applications can use those ports without superuser permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3810129 check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you think it solved your problem.